# Partial order on the set of ordinal functions

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

Let $\kappa$ be a regular ordinal.

Say that for $f,g: \kappa \rightarrow \kappa$, $f \leq g$ iff $f(\alpha)  \leq g(\alpha)$ for sufficiently large $\alpha$. Now define $(X_{\kappa},\preceq)$ as the quotient poset $({\kappa}^{\kappa},\leq) / \sim$ where $f \sim g$ iff $ f \leq g \wedge g \leq f$.

Note that $X_{\kappa}$ is never well-founded since $\mathbb{N} \ni n \longmapsto (\kappa \ni \alpha \mapsto \alpha - n)$, it being understood that if $\alpha$ is not the $n^{th}$ successor of some ordinal, then $\alpha-n$ is the biggest limit ordinal $\leq \alpha$, is stricly decreasing. (or rather the sequence of equivalence classes is)

I have three questions regarding this relatively simple construction, possibly in decreasing order of difficulty:

$(i)$: Do we know the supremum of the set of ordinals which embed in $(X_{\kappa},\prec)$?

$(ii)$: Do we know $cof(X_{\kappa},\prec)$?

$(iii)$: Is there a definable embedding of $\omega_1$ into $X_{\omega_0}$?

It isn't difficult to see that $cof(X_{\kappa},\prec) > \kappa$ because given an increasing sequence $u: \kappa \rightarrow X_{\kappa}$, the equivalence class of $f:\kappa \ni \alpha \longmapsto \sup(\{u(\beta)(\alpha) \ | \ \beta \leq \alpha\}) + 1$ is a strict upper bound of $u$. However I can't think of a constructive way to embed (cofinally or not) ${\kappa}^+$ in $X_{\kappa}$.

Comment: The first two are really generalized "continuum characteristics". I don't know the answer, but I'd imagine it can be independent of ZFC. For the third one, definable in what sense (and in particular, what sort of parameters you're allowing, if any)?

Comment: Definable in ZFC, no limitation on the sort of parameters. So can  you imagine that $cof(X_{\omega_0},\prec) = \omega_1$ be undecidable in ZFC as well?

Comment: Definable is a semantic property. And surely you can't mean what you said, because then you can just use any embedding that you'd like as a parameter to define itself. So you might want to mean something like a formula which is provably going to provide you with an embedding? But then things get quite tricky indeed, because using homogeneous forcing we can ensure not to change the interpretation of any definable set, while changing the value of $\omega_1$, which will invariably require a different approach.

Comment: Yes sorry, I kind of thought to myself you could use any countable ordinal or sequence of natural integers as a parameter but not any set in the universe. Unfortunately I am not familiar with forcing. What you wrote seems to suggest that there is a distinction between the value and the interpretation of a definition, what is it?

Comment: Well, if $M$ is a countable model of ZFC, then there is a bijection between $\omega$ and $\omega_1^M$ (not in $M$). We can add such a bijection in some situations without adding ordinals to the model (read: forcing is used here). The result is that what was $\omega_1$ of $M$ is now a countable ordinal in the new model; so a larger ordinal has become the "new" $\omega_1$. And so on. We can do similar things with other formulas which provably define a set; and we can sometimes do it in a way that breaks even more "intuitive" things when we think in a terms of a single universe.

Comment: This is very impressive, thank you. Maybe it is time I learned about forcing.

Comment: Yes. It is time.